# determine where a POST is coming from, in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I have a simple comment form on my site that allows you to post on your own profile (think the facebook wall)...I want to put this form on both the home page, and on the users profile page.

the problem is, I want the ajax to respond differently depending on which page it is coming from.  I can't seem to find a way to differentiate where the post is coming from (the home controller vs. the users controller)

I've tried the following:

if page['profile']
if request.request_uri = "/home"
and even using a hidden field in the form

but none of them work.  Is there a reliable way to determine where in the app the POST is coming from for the Comments create action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `params[:controller]`, `params[:action]` and `params[:method]` what you're looking for?

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for me, as the controller and action are the same in the params (controller: message, params: new) no matter if the request is coming from the homepage or the users profile show page.